# Is there a continuous transition between deterministic and stochastic?

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling

This is perhaps a more philosophical question. Hence, I'm looking for philosophical answers but more concrete ones or maybe directions to books or articles about it would also be of help.

During my different studies in mathematics it seems like the field has always been separated into two branches: 'stochastic mathematics' and 'deterministic mathematics' (and after this, more branches).

'Stochastic' involves some sort of probability and we always deal with distributions. Deterministic however involves *no* randomness.

Even though it logically seems right to completely separate these, I've wondered if there exists a continuous transition between the two. Just think of pseudo-random systems. Most computer programs dealing with stochastic values is actually not stochastic. Is it theoretically possible to make a pseudo-random process that ultimately becomes random?

I don't know much about how to create pseudo-random processes - maybe that would be a point of departure towards an answer?

What do you think? Are those two fields meant to be separated or does it make sense to ask my question?

Comment: Do you believe in the law of the excluded middle?

Comment: @SenZen ... say the tortoise to Achilles.